# Angularjs ng-paste on select component

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-paste component on select components?
I can put it working on text componentes, but I want to do the same on Select Box. Imagine that I want 10 rows, if I paste the 9th value the ideal is to select them.

plunkr example :

```
<select ng-model="myselect" ng-options="o for o in options" ng-paste="paste2()" ></select>
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/QmpeAjyCRzAQsx1hxqAE?p=preview)

Comment: how do you paste to the select? [ng-paste](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPaste) I think you are misinterpreting the use of it...

Comment: select boxes don't have an `onPaste` event handler, and it wouldn't make sense anyway, since they aren't *technically* an input.

Comment: It might be a silly question but imagine that I click on the selectobox and I paste "car3" to select that value.

Comment: you can have an input box and a select box that have the same `ng-model`, and when you paste into the input it can select the matching option in the select.  but pasting directly into the select isn't something that is in the HTML spec.

Comment: Ok, Thank you all for your help and explanation!